# CSS selector issue, focused input isn't properly selected

Tags: html, css

I am strangling with CSS overlay...
My sample has two sets of input tags with label on top of it
Clicking on the first number nicely switches to the edit mode.
Unfortunately, clicking on the second number doesn't really work as expected.

```css
div[class="number_container"]>input:focus+label {
  display: none
}

.number_container {
  position: relative;
}

.number_content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 1px;
  left: 1px;
  height: 22px;
  width: 148px;
  text-align: center;
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="number_container">
    <input id="1" name="1" style="width: 150px;" type="number" value="100000">
    <label class="number_content" for="1">$1,000,014</label>
  </div>

  <br/>
  <br/>
  <div class="number_container">
    <input id="2" name="2" style="width: 150px;" type="number" value="200000">
    <label class="number_content" for="1">$2,000,014</label>
  </div>
</body>
```

it seems that CSS selector somehow selects the first div element 
Nevertheless it works with tab key

any help highly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue is about you have mentioned `for="1"` that refers first input automatically when you focus on second input. So change it to `"2"` will solve the issue. check below snippet for reference.

```css
div[class="number_container"]>input:focus+.number_content {
  display: none
}

.number_container {
  position: relative;
}

.number_content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 1px;
  left: 1px;
  height: 22px;
  width: 148px;
  text-align: center;
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="number_container">
    <input id="1" name="1" style="width: 150px;" type="number" value="100000">
    <label class="number_content" for="1">$1,000,014</label>
  </div>

  <br/>
  <br/>
  <div class="number_container">
    <input id="2" name="2" style="width: 150px;" type="number" value="200000">
    <label class="number_content" for="2">$2,000,014</label>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

try changing the "for" of your second label to "2" so it matches with the second input